# How to generate a random string and compute the percent of a specific string?

Tags: r, string, random

I'm doing my first ever R course. One of the exercises is to create a random DNA strings with 1000 bases and for it compute the GC percentage
(GC%).

I created the DNA bases vector and tried to create the sequence, however, the result is not correct

```
DNA <- c("A","G","T","C")
seq <- strrep(DNA, 250)
```

Any suggestion for this noob?

Comment: Try `sample(DNA, 1000, replace=TRUE)` and if you really need it to be a single string, just paste it together: `paste(sample(DNA, 1000, replace=TRUE), collapse="")`

Comment: Do you want the percent of bases equal to G or C or do you want the percent with consecutive GC bases? If you want the latter do `library(stringr); chain <- paste(sample(DNA, 1000, replace = T), collapse=""); str_count(chain, "GC")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you should check out very basics of `R`, i.e `sum`, `sample`, `paste` functions. The solution is quite simple:

```
DNA <- c("A","G","T","C")
chain <- sample(DNA, 1000, replace = T)
GCcontent <- sum(chain %in% c('G','C'))/length(chain)
# chain as a string
paste(chain, collapse="")
```